# Simple one line class method returning wrong value

Tags: c++, date, inheritance, output

I am having a weird issue and I don't know what's wrong.

I have a class `publication` composed of the class members `string headline` and `string text`.

I also have a class called `publication_and_date` which inherits from `publication`, but also has an additional field called `string date` which represents the date a certain article was published.

I also have a class `news` that inherits from `publication_and_date`, and has the additional field of `string sources`

The problem is this: I have an object of type `news`, and when i use the method `get_date` of that object, I get the value `M`.

Here is my void main:

```
void main()
{
    news MyNews;

    MyNews.set_date(3,12,2016);
    MyNews.set_sources("IGN");
    MyNews.set_headline("MGS V wins GOTY award");
    MyNews.set_text("Metal Gear Solid V won the prestigious game of the year award!");

    cout << MyNews.ToString();
    getch();
}
```

This is the implementation of the class `publication_and_date`:

```
publication_and_date::publication_and_date() : publication()
{
    date="1/9/2015";
}

void publication_and_date::set_date(const int NewDay,const int NewMonth,const int NewYear)
{
    if((NewDay > 31)||(NewDay < 1)||(NewMonth > 12)||(NewMonth < 1)||(NewYear<2015)) //input check
    {
        cout << "\nDate is invalid\n";
        return;
    }
    date=NewDay + '/' + NewMonth + '/' + NewYear;
}

string publication_and_date::get_date()
{
    return date;
}
```

As you can see, the method `get_date()` is very simple. It's just one line.

I don't know why the value I'm getting is `M`.

The output of the void main I gave you is:

```
Headline: MGS V wins GOTY award
Text: Metal Gear Solid V won the prestigious game of the year award!
Date: M
Sources: IGN
```

I'm completely baffled as to why this happens. Would appreciate help.

Edit1: This is the code for ToString

```
string news::ToString()
{
    string ToReturn;
    ToReturn="\nHeadline: " + get_headline() + '\n' + "Text: " + get_text() + '\n'+"Date: " + get_date()+'\n'+"Sources: " + get_sources();
    return ToReturn;
}
```

Edit2:

I think I know what the problem is. `NewDay, NewMonth,NewYear` are integers. So the `+` operator is not the same as with strings. I need to somehow make them chars.

Comment: We'll need the code for `ToString`

Comment: It should be `int main`.

Comment: Edited. Also I know what the problem is, I don't know how to fix it yet. The line I wrote for "set_date" at the end is wrong, since I'm trying to concat integers, and + doesnt work that way on integers. I need to somehow make those integers characters.

Comment: `date=NewDay + '/' + NewMonth + '/' + NewYear;`  C++ is not JavaScript.  You are mixing `int` with `std::string`.

Comment: Yes I just realized this as well. How do I "convert" NewDay NewMonth and NewYear to characters so I can concat?

Comment: Posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) avoids all these back and forth comments. Please keep that in mind. If you can post an MCVE even now, it will be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an `M` or something else random because you add up the numbers rather than concatenate strings. A char `'/'` is actually a small integer with the value of 47.

One way to convert everything into a string is to use a `stringstream` (located in sstream header):

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << NewDay << '/' << NewMonth << '/' << NewYear;
date = ss.str();
```

A string stream is just like your regular iostream, but it works on strings. It will do the right thing with regards of type conversions.